# Why does a `.then` callback following a `.catch` get executed?

Tags: javascript, promise

**Problem:** last 2 `.then` are getting called even while I am returning `Promise.reject()`. The 1st `.then()` is printing undefined and 2nd `.then()` is also printing the output.

Can someone please explain why?

```
let p4 = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    resolve("p4 Resolved");
});

p4.then((val)=>{
    console.log(val);
    return Promise.reject("20 Rejected")
}).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
  .then((val)=>{console.log(val);return 290})
  .then((val)=>{console.log("Last then : "+val);});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`catch` also returns a promise and since you didn't return anything, it will be a promise that fulfills to `undefined`, therefore the first `then` prints `undefined`. Finally, the last `then` gets the value 290 from the previously returned promise by the first `then` and prints it.

Comment: thank you bro cleared the doubt <3 keep up the good work

Answer (score 2):

`.catch()` returns a new pending `Promise`:

> Returns a new Promise. This new promise is always pending when
> returned, regardless of the current promise's status. It's eventually
> rejected if onRejected throws an error or returns a Promise which is
> itself rejected; otherwise, it's eventually fulfilled.
> — [`Promise#catch()`, *Return value* | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch#return_value)

The first `.then()` returns a rejected promise, which as you expect, calls `.catch()`. However, since the callback passed to it as argument (`error => { console.log(error) }`) doesn't throw any errors, the new promise will be fulfilled and therefore it will call all the subsequent `.then()`s.

Answer (score -1):

When you nest multiple .then() functions in a Promise chain, each .then() function will be executed one after the other in the order they were chained.

The result of each .then() function is passed on to the next .then() function in the chain as a parameter. This allows you to perform a sequence of asynchronous operations and handle the results step-by-step.

link reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#chaining